# Send value from Flask to Javascript variable in javascript file script

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am new to HTML and Javascript. I am having a Python dictionary from flask which I want to assign to javascript variable I tried the below systax but I am getting error.I looks like the value is not getting into javascript as my code is incorrect pls assist.

error = Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')

Flask

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['POST'])
def get_d():
    pr_data = {'pr_data':['toyota','vw','GMC']}
    return jsonify(pr_data)
```

html

```
<div id="pr_data" data-pr_data={{pr_data}}></div>
```

javascript

```
var pr_data= JSON.parse(document.getElementById("pr_data").value)
```

Comment: You need quotes around `{{pr_data}}`. Use single quotes because there will be double quotes in the JSON.

Comment: The error means you're trying to call `document.getElementById()` before the element has been added to the DOM. Make sure the `<script>` is after the `<div>`, or use run the code in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener.

Comment: `.value` should be `.dataset.pr_value`. `.value` is for the value of an input field.

Comment: I tried below but still getting same error sir.

<div  id="pr_data" data-pr-data='{{pr_data}}'></div>

var tickers =  document.getElementById("pr_data").dataset.pr_data.value;

Comment: `var pr_data= JSON.parse(document.getElementById("pr_data").dataset.pr_data);`. No `.value`.

Comment: Did you fix the problem with `getElementById()` not finding the element? See the linked question.

Comment: Hello Sir, 

Yes, I have tried still getting same error


`<div id="pr_data" data-pr-data='{{pr_data}}'></div>`

`var tickers= JSON.parse(document.getElementById("pr_data").dataset.pr_data);`

Comment: The error is in JavaScript, not Python. That code is irrelevant.

Comment: Can you see the DIV in the Elements inspector of DevTools?

Comment: I am getting the same null value error. It appears that my html is also wrong here.

Comment: `<div id="pr_data" data-pr-data></div>`  this is what I see in inspect in chrome

Comment: So it's not substituting `{{pr_data}}` into the template. That's a problem, but it won't cause "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')"

Comment: Where are you calling `render_template()`?

Comment: I have added in a saperate function sir above the pr_data function
`@app.route('/')
def cars():
   return render_template('cars.html')`

Comment: You need something like `render_template('cars.html', pr_data=get_d())`

Comment: Hello Sir,

I think html issue is fixed I can see json in inspect console in chrome but javascript variable is still getting null error.



`<div id="pr_data" data-pr_data="{'pr_data': ['vw',toyota']}"></div>`

`var tickers= JSON.parse(document.getElementById("pr_data").dataset.pr_data);`
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dataset')

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON requires double quotes around strings, not single quotes. I don't know how you got that from `jsonify()` or `json.dumps()`.

Comment: So it should be `data-pr_data='{"pr_data": ["vw", "toyota"]}'`

Comment: Hello Sir, 

Its fixed now I can see value is getting assigned to Javascript variable. Thanks a lot for assisting